# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when using ejs in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am following The Net Nijna's tutorial on youtube.
I reached tutorial number 27, working with partials in ejs. Everything works until I add the <% include partials/nav.js %>, once I add this code I recieve:

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in *(file location)* testapp\views\profile.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function ()..... blah blah blah...

If I remove it, my ejs all works fine.

```
  <body>
    <% include partials/nav.ejs %>

    <h1>Welcome to the profile of <%= person %> !</h1>
    <p><strong> Age: <%= data.age %></strong></p>

    <p><strong> Job: <%= data.job %></strong></p>
    <p><strong> Pet: <%= data.pet %></strong></p>
    <h2>Hobbies</h2>
    <ul>
      <% data.hobbies.forEach(function(item){ %>
        <li><%= item %></li>
      <%});%>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

can you help a student out? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Try <%- include('partials/nav') %> or <%- include partials/nav.ejs %>

Comment: tried the second one, didn't work but your first one did! BAM! Thanks a bajillion!

Comment: You're very welcome

Answer (score 6):

Missing hyphen and need to invoke the include function.

```
 <%- include('partials/nav') %>
```

Comment: For readers of Express in Action by Evan Hahn, this fixes an error in the code of the sample app in Chapter 3.    Thanks Joseph!

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck at the same problem and used `-include('#filename');`
it worked

Answer (score -1):

Use: <%- include('folder/file') %>

- agreeing with @Joseph Varilla
- Not necessary to include engine extension as this should have been done in app.js or index.js file